# Vowel mutations not correct on some devices

Tags: php, internationalization, diacritics

I'm from Germany and we got vowel mutations over here (ä, ü,ö etc). The problem is, that these arent displayed correctly on some devices (mostly mobile phones) when receiving an email via contact form. Im using the following php code

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"; charset="utf-8" />

<?php 
$errors = '';
$myemail = 'emailadress@email.com';
if(empty($_POST['name'])  || 
   empty($_POST['email']) || 
   empty($_POST['message']))
{
    $errors .= "\n Error: all fields are required";
}

$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email_address = $_POST['email']; 
$message = $_POST['message']; 

if (!preg_match(
"/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i", 
$email_address))
{
    $errors .= "\n Error: Invalid email address";
}

if( empty($errors))
{
 $to = $myemail; 
 $email_subject = "Sie haben eine neue Nachricht von: $name";
 $email_body = "Sie haben eine neue Nachricht erhalten, hier sind die Details: \n\nName: $name \nEmail: $email_address \nNachricht: \n$message"; 
 
 $headers .= 'From: <WSC Kontaktformular>' . "\r\n";
 $headers = "Reply-To: {$email_address}";
 $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
 $headers = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1";
 
 mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,implode("\r\n",$headers));
 //redirect to the 'thank you' page
 header('Location: contact-form-thank-you.html');
} 
?>
```

Do you have any idea why there is a problem on mobile devices but not on desktop computers or laptops?

Comment: Well, your page is in UTF-8 but the email you send out has ISO-8859-1, what do you expect. Solution: do everything in UTF-8.

Comment: Yeah, I see that ;) But I tried without the charset at the top, didnt work. Tried with iso-9959-1 in it, didnt work, tried with utf-8 at the bottom one, didnt work either. So what am I supposed to change? Sry Im no PHP expert.

Comment: If the PHP page itself is in UTF-8, then all the fields should be UTF-8 too and there should be no problems. So check in the browser if the page is indeed UTF-8. I know the meta element says so, but there may be a HTTP header messing with things. Also, there is an error in how you make your mail headers. It will not send all of them, only the last one. Whoever wrote this probably meant to write `$headers[] = ...` instead of `$headers = ...`

Comment: Yes, the whole page is in UTF-8. I deleted the iso-8859-1, but it still isnt working. The page is www.wscgmbh.de

Comment: If you are certain that everything has the same charset, then I don't know where the problems come from, sorry. You should definitely fix the `$headers[]` issue though.